# Connect custom web part to a library web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, connected-web-parts

I'm creating a custom web part using SPFx and I'll to connect it to a list. The web part I make shows the details of a product. The library I'll connect contains all manuals of the all the products. I'll filter that library depended on the selected product in my custom web part.

How can I do this? I don't find anything on the web or a setting to do this.

I don't want to create new web part for the library.

Comment: What is your question then? please narrow down your issue and be specific while asking a question. It will be easy for other users to understand and answer your question.

Comment: @GaneshSanap: I'm sorry, I've added my question.